# Spirit X3, two rules do not compile after being combined into one

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am currently learning how to use x3. As the title states, I have had success creating a grammar with a few simple rules, but upon combining two of these rules into one, the code no longer compiles. Here is the code for the AST portion:

```
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct Expression;

struct FunctionExpression {
    std::string functionName;
    std::vector<x3::forward_ast<Expression>> inputs;
};

struct Expression: x3::variant<int, double, bool, FunctionExpression> {
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};
```

The rules I have created parse input formatted as `{rangeMin, rangeMax}`:

```
rule<struct basic_exp_class, ast::Expression> const
    basic_exp = "basic_exp";
rule<struct exp_pair_class, std::vector<ast::Expression>> const 
    exp_pair = "exp_pair";
rule<struct range_class, ast::FunctionExpression> const 
    range = "range";

auto const basic_exp_def = double_ | int_ | bool_;
auto const exp_pair_def = basic_expr >> ',' >> basic_expr;
auto const range_def = attr("computeRange") >> '{' >> exp_pair >> '}';

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(basic_expr, exp_pair_def, range_def);
```

This code compiles fine. However, if I try to inline the `exp_pair` rule into the `range_def` rule, like so:

```
rule<struct basic_exp_class, ast::Expression> const
    basic_exp = "basic_exp";
rule<struct range_class, ast::FunctionExpression> const 
    range = "range";

auto const basic_exp_def = double_ | int_ | bool_;
auto const range_def = attr("computeRange") >> '{' >> (
    basic_exp >> ',' >> basic_exp
) >> '}';

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(basic_expr, range_def);
```

The code fails to compile with a very long template error, ending with the line:

```
spirit/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/sequence.hpp:149:9: error: static assertion failed: Size of the passed attribute is less than expected.
     static_assert(
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The header file also includes this comment above the `static_assert`:

```
// If you got an error here, then you are trying to pass
// a fusion sequence with the wrong number of elements
// as that expected by the (sequence) parser.
```

But I do not see why the code should fail. According to x3's [compound attribute rules](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html), the inlined portion in the parenthesis should have an attribute of type `vector<ast::Expression>`, making the overall rule have the type `tuple<string, vector<ast::Expression>`, so that it would be compatible with `ast::FunctionExpression`. The same logic applies the more verbose three-rule version, the only difference being that I specifically declared a rule for the inner part and specifically stated its attribute needed to be of type `vector<ast::Expression>`.

Comment: It probably is seeing the inlined rule as two Expression instead of vector<Expected>, another answer has a helper `as` so that you can specify the type.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932608/boost-spirit-x3-attribute-does-not-have-the-expected-size-redux can't try it now so don't know if it works.

Comment: @BobBills Thanks, I was gonna post the same idea as a comment :)

Comment: @BobBills this is exactly what I was looking for. By including the `as` lambda, i can change the rule to `auto const range_def = attr("computeRange") >> '{' >> as<std::vector<ast::Expression>>(basic_exp >> ',' >> basic_exp) >> '}';`, and it compiles sucessfully. Could you put your suggestion into a full answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Why do you want to inline it? That's what rules for. If you pass a tuple (`FunctionExpression`) to a sequence parser (`... >> ...`), Spirit will not do any magic (will not try to do a sequence collapse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spirit x3 is probably seeing the result of the inlined rule as two separate `ast::Expression` instead of the `std::vector<ast::Expression>` required by the `ast::FunctionExpression` struct.

To solve it we can use a helper `as` lambda as mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49937769/6301944) to specify the return type of a sub-rule.

And the modified range_def would become:

```
auto const range_def = attr("computeRange") >> '{' >> as<std::vector<ast::Expression>>(basic_exp >> ',' >> basic_exp) >> '}';
```