# Boost Spirit X3: error: no type named 'size' in '...'

Tags: c++, boost, struct

Im trying to parse into a struct containing a std::string and std::vector, but I always get a error when using the %-operator of Boost Spirit.

I already tried to isolate the list parsing into a seperate rule ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252680/boost-spirit-x3-parser-no-type-named-type-in)) and the `as<>`-directive from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932608/boost-spirit-x3-attribute-does-not-have-the-expected-size-redux)

Without the `predicate_arguments` rule it works perfectly.

The error is pretty big, some snippets:

```
[...] error: static assertion failed: The parser expects tuple-like attribute type
[...] error: no type named 'size' in 'struct dec::predicate_query'
[...] error: no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::fusion::extension::size_impl<boost::fusion::non_fusion_tag>::apply<dec::predicate_query>'
[...] error: non-constant condition for static assertion
```

decfile_parser.cpp

```
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

x3::rule<class predicate_name, std::string> predicate_name = "predicate_name";
x3::rule<class predicate_query, dec::predicate_query> predicate_query = "predicate_query";
x3::rule<class predicate_arguments, std::vector<dec::predicate_argument_type>> predicate_arguments = "predicate_arguments";
x3::rule<class predicate_argument, dec::predicate_argument_type> predicate_argument = "predicate_argument";

auto const predicate_query_def = predicate_name >> '(' >> predicate_arguments  >> ')';
auto const predicate_arguments_def = predicate_argument % ',';
auto const predicate_name_def = *x3::char_("a-zA-Z");
// TODO: sortname
auto const predicate_argument_def = *x3::char_("a-zA-Z") | predicate_query;

decfile_parser::decfile_parser() {

}

void decfile_parser::parse_file(std::string filename) {
    int value = 0;
    std::string str("HoldsAt(Pos(), test)");
    std::string::iterator strbegin = str.begin();

    x3::phrase_parse(strbegin,
                     str.end(),
                     predicate_query,
                     x3::ascii::blank);

}

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(predicate_query, predicate_name, predicate_argument, predicate_arguments);

int main() {
    decfile_parser par;
    par.parse_file("test.e2");
}
```

decfile_parser.h

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

#include <string>

#include "ast.h"

class decfile_parser {
public:
    decfile_parser();
    ~decfile_parser() = default;

    void parse_file(std::string filename);
};
```

ast.h

```
namespace dec {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;


    struct predicate_query;
    typedef x3::variant<std::string, x3::forward_ast<predicate_query>> predicate_argument_type;

    struct predicate_query {
        std::string name;
        std::vector<predicate_argument_type> arguments;
    };
}
```

ast_adapted.h

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include "ast.h"

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        dec::predicate_query,
        (std::string, name),
        (std::vector<dec::predicate_argument_type>, arguments)
        )
```

Edit 1: Maybe its because he wants to parse `name` and `arguments` into one container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to import the `ast_adapted.h` into my `decfile_parser.h`. The error was because the struct of course was not adapted to a Fusion Sequence.